# Problema rellenando objeto con node y mongodb

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo la siguiente función

```
function getParadas(req,res){

  var find;
  let paradas ={
    paradasMetro:[],
    paradasCercanias:[],
    paradasBus:[]
  }
  var find1= ParadasMetro.find().sort('nombre_parada');
  var find2= ParadasCercanias.find().sort('nombre_parada');
  var find3= ParadasBus.find().sort('nombre_parada');

    find1.exec((err,paradasM) => {
      if(err){
        console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas metro)');
      }else{
        if(!paradasM){
          console.log('No hay paradas de metro');
        }else{
          paradas.paradasMetro=paradasM;
        }
      }
    });

    find2.exec((err,paradasC) => {
      if(err){
        console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas cercanias)');
      }else{
        if(!paradasC){
          console.log('No hay paradas de cercanias');
        }else{
          paradas.paradasCercanias=paradasC;
          console.log(paradas);
        }
      }
    });

    find3.exec((err,paradasB) => {
      if(err){
        console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas bus)');
      }else{
        if(!paradasB){
          console.log('No hay paradas de bus');
        }else{
          paradas.paradasBus=paradasB;
        }
      }
    });
    console.log(paradas);

      res.status(200).send({
      paradasResponse:paradas,
    });

}
```

Mi problema es a la hora de rellenar el objeto `paradas`. Cuando llega al `console.log(paradas)` de dentro de la funcion `find2.exec()` me pinta lo siguiente:

```
{ paradasMetro: [],
  paradasCercanias:
   [ { _id: 598c9fe410ebd9a7a9445c52,
       nombre_parada: 'Aeropuerto T4',
       lineas: '1' },
    /*Muchas mas paradas*/
     { _id: 598c9fe410ebd9a7a9445bf2,
       nombre_parada: 'Zarzaquemada',
       lineas: '5' } ],
  paradasBus: [] }
```

Es decir, me reconoce el objeto `paradas` creado arriba pero me lo reinicia en la ejecución de cada `find#.exec` ya que para cuando ha llegado a este `console.log()` ya ha pasado por el `find1.exec()` y ha tenido que llenar el de `paradas.paradasMetro`, pero me lo pinta vació. Y ya cuando llega al `console.log()` del final, me pinta todos los objetos vacíos

```
{ paradasMetro: [], paradasCercanias: [], paradasBus: [] }
```

¿Alguna idea de porque puede ser?

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que es porque tus consultas se hacen asincróncamente, no sincrónicamente. Es decir, tu res.status(200).send() se ejecuta *al final mientras las consultas pueden o no haber terminado sus oepraciones y cambiado tu objeto*.

Primero te recomiendo reestructurar tus peticiones así:

```
 find1.exec((err,paradasM) => {
  if(err)
    console.log('Error en la peticion(Paradas metro)');

  if(!paradasM){
    console.log('No hay paradas de metro');

  paradas.paradasMetro=paradasM;
});
```

Es más limpio sin tener tantas llaves.

Y segundo, puedes colocar los callbacks anidados pero te dará un callback hell (anti patrón que te hace el código inmantenible), por lo tanto te sugiero usar promesas, puedes consultar sobre ellas [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) o [aquí](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises?hl=es)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, pa matarme no verlo..

Answer (score 2):

Aunque ya haya una respuesta aceptada, te pondré un ejemplo usando promesas y funciones asíncronas. Esto puedes usarlo a partir de Node 7.8 en adelante.

> **No uses modelos en los controladores.** Esta es una mala práctica; hace tu código más acoplado y difícil de manejar. Cada modelo debe tener su respectivo **servicio** que será usado por los controladores.

Tu código puede verse muy simplificado si empiezas a usar ES6+:

```
exports.getParadas = async () => {
  const paradas = {};

  try {
    paradas.metro = await ParadasMetro.find().sort('nombre_parada');
    paradas.cercanias = await ParadasCercanias.find().sort('nombre_parada');
    paradas.bus = await ParadasBus.find().sort('nombre_parada');
    return paradas;
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  }
};

router.get('/paradas', (req, res) => {
  service
    .getParadas()
    .then(paradas => res.jsonp(paradas))
    .catch(e => res.status(500).send(e.message));
});
```

Respecto a lo que te comentaron de las llaves, pues es de preferencia personal, sin embargo la mayoría de estilos nos recomienda usarlos ([referencia a ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/curly)).

Comment: Muy buena sugerencia sobre no usar modelos en los controladores directamente para desacoplar. Y de acuerdo con lo de las llaves (y)